# Retrieving phone number from Android list

Tags: android, listview

So here is the code,it displays the list of all contacts in the list but if i want to send the contact name through string name by using bundle how do i do that.What am i missing to access the phone number and name?

```
    public class Contacts extends ListActivity 
{
    ListView lv;
    Cursor cursor1;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cursor1=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);

        String[] from= {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};

        int[] to= {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor1, from, to );

        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

        lv= getListView();
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object listItem = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String name=listItem.toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Chat.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                              //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
                bundle.putString("CHAT_NAME", name);
                //Add the bundle to the intent
                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                //Fire the second activity
                startActivity(intent);
                }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public long getSelectedItemId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }}
```